# systemd After=nginx.service is not working

Tags: linux, systemd

I am trying to setup a custom systemd service on my linux system and was experimenting with it
Following is my custom service, where it will trigger a bash file

```
[Unit]
Description=Example systemd service.
After=nginx.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/test_service.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Since I have mentioned `After=nginx.service` i was expecting nginx serivce to start automatically
So after starting the above service, i check the status of nginx, which has not started

However if i replace `After` with `Wants` it works
Can someone differenciate between `After` and `Wants` and when to use what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifying `After=foo` tells systemd how to order the units if they are both started at the same time. It will not cause the `foo` unit to autostart.

Use `After=foo` in combination with `Wants=foo` or `Requires=foo` to start `foo` if it's not already started and also to keep desired order of the units.

So your [Unit] should include:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example systemd service.
After=nginx.service
Wants=nginx.service
```

Difference between `Wants` and `Requires`:

> Wants= : This directive is similar to Requires= , but less strict. Systemd will attempt to start any units listed here when this unit is activated. If these units are not found or fail to start, the current unit will continue to function. This is the recommended way to configure most dependency relationships.